# Mir-libs and mir-kiosk on RPi3 with Ubuntu Core

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, mir

I've tried to get the mir-kiosk snap on Ubuntu Core, on a Raspberry Pi 3, running. Installation progress went fine, using these two tutorials;
* http://voices.canonical.com/alan.griffiths/2017/01/31/mircade-snap/
* http://www.lieberbiber.de/2017/02/27/mir-and-graphics-on-ubuntu-core/

One person has made a comment about it working flawlessly on Raspberry Pi 3, but it doesn't on my side. I've tried the suggested "snap connection" without any luck.

I don't get any error messages. Have tried many reboots and reinstalls.

Any suggestions?

The pi have both Ethernet and WiFi connection. Connected to a 40 TV through HDMI.

Comment: Contact the person who maintains those packages.

Comment: Hm, thought if someone has a suggestion I could try out, I wouldn't have to bother him with such questions.

Comment: Well you can hope someone with more experience with these packages come along.

Comment: Yeah, sure. That's why I'm posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to be trying this just last week, and stumbled across a bug which I presume was causing your problems:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/opengl-interface-change-in-master-broke-gles-on-the-pi-devices/1947/5

There is a workaround mentioned there, but a newer core snap has the proper fix integrated.

So I'd recommend using the Daily/Edge RPi3 image available [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/edge/current/) (it also has reliably working wifi).
Next install the core snap from the edge channel, and then you can follow Alan Griffith's guide.

-G